# Why is the column not starting at the top of the page with ieeetran

Tags: floats, ieeetran

This is an intermittent problem I am having.  Sometimes it aligns sometimes it does not.  I have not been able to replicate it with dummy text.  Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?  Resizing the image does not fix it.

Thanks,
Mike
[image: column not aligning]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you talking about the big gap (presumably due to using figure* instead of figure) or the extra stretch between lines?

Answer (score 1):

Had to remove

```
\usepackage{stfloats}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).